# can I make a list of types in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, types, instance

I have different data types that I have defined, and I want to make them all an instance of a class. is it possible to make a list of types and map instance over them instead of having to declare them all individually?

I mean something like this:

```
data Type1 = ...
data Type2 = ...

map (instance ClassName) [Type1, Type2]
```

Comment: Unless all these types can be rewritten in the form `F x y ...` for a single type `F`, with different parameters, I think the only option is generating the instances through Template Haskell. It is not very convenient, so it is worth the candle only if you have many instances to write.

Comment: What would `map (instance ClassName)` do, exactly? `map` takes a list and does the same thing to each item. Are all your instances identical? Then the types must be identical, too, so why have different types? Or is `ClassName` an empty class? Then what's it for?

Comment: I'm using aeson to do json transformations, you can use generic to have types automatically declared as instances of from and to json, so creating different types to represent json data. in this case all you do is make the type an instance of those classes and they don't require further definition, with several types needed to represent different json data it makes sense to me to just map instance over each type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well actually you can, with something like

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module T where

class C a

data X = X
data Y = Y
data Z = Z

$(fmap concat $ mapM (\t -> [d|instance C $t|]) [[t|X|], [t|Y|], [t|Z|]])
```

but it strikes me as massive overkill unless you actually need them to be generated automatically (e.g., the list of types might vary depending on something).